# Linked list: how to make sorter checker in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I thought this should work correctly...I'm not sure what's wrong with it? Here's a snippet of my code. It's suppose to return 0 if the given list of integers are not in ascending order and return 1 if it is in ascending order.

```
 struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *pNext;
 };

 int isItSorted(Node *pHead){
    while(pHead != NULL){
       if(pHead->data > pHead->pNext->data) 
          return 0;
       else
          return 1;
       pHead = pHead->pNext;
    }
    return 1;
 }
```

Comment: Your code will encounter undefined behaviour because you don't verify that `pHead->pNext != NULL` before dereferencing it. This may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Also, please post your code that creates the list - it's possible you aren't initializing the fields correctly (such as explicitly setting `pNext` to `NULL` when appropriate).

Comment: Your code will never perform more than one iteration of the loop, because there is an unconditional `return` in the loop body.

Comment: Your code returns after comparing two nodes, as expected by `if(pHead->data > pHead->pNext->data) return 0; else return 1;`... Whether inside a loop or not, this will compare two nodes and return. If you don't want it to return, remove the `return` keyword (hint: you *really do* want to `return` in *one* of these branches, but *not the other*); you need to put some *other logic* there... **Where's your book?**

Answer (score 1):

You invoke undefined behavior, as @Dai said, when you do `pHead->pNext->data` without first checking `pHead->pNext != NULL`. Additionally, as @JohnBollinger said, you have a `return 1` *inside* the `while`, so it will return after checking `list[0] < list[1]` instead of going through the entire thing.

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *pNext;
};

int isItSorted(Node *pHead){
   while(pHead != NULL && pHead->pNext != NULL) { // 0 and 1 element lists are always sorted, so this is fine.
      if(pHead->data > pHead->pNext->data) 
          return 0; // Break out and return
      else
          pHead = pHead->pNext; // Or keep going
   }
   return 1; // Lift out end case from loop
}
```

Here's a tail-recursive version, too: (EDIT: Neither `clang` nor `gcc` appear to be smart enough to notice the tail-recursion, even with `-O3`. Oh well.)

```
int isSorted(Node *list) {
  return list == NULL // [] is sorted
      || list->pNext == NULL // [x] is sorted
      || list->data <= list->pNext->data && isSorted(list->pNext); // x:y:z is sorted if x < y and y:z is sorted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your (major) problem:

```
if(pHead->data > pHead->pNext->data) 
   return 0;
else
   return 1;
```

Doing this inside your loop will return one or zero *immediately,* based only on the comparison of the first two items. That's assuming you *have* at least two items in there, otherwise you have undefined behaviour because you dereference the null pointer.

I would implement it as follows (pseudo-code), with plain checks up front to catch the edge cases (less than two items), and *continuing* to check items for ordering rather than returning after a single check:

```
def isSorted(head):
    # Less than two items means sorted no matter what the data is.

    if head == NULL:
        return true

    if head.next == NULL:
        return true

    # Continue while there are at least two items to check.

    node = head
    while node.next != NULL:
        # If those two items out of order, it'snot sorted.
        # If they are in order, advance and keep checking.

        if node.data > node.next.data:
            return false
        node = node.next

    # Reaching here means all items were in order.

    return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one mistake in your code:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *pNext;
 };

 int isItSorted(Node *pHead){
    while(pHead != NULL){
       if(pHead->next != NULL && pHead->data > pHead->pNext->data) {
          return 0;
       }
       pHead = pHead->pNext;
    }
    return 1;
 }
```

whenever dealing with loops, make sure you check your exit conditions.
For example, in your code, if it is not going into the IF block, then it is bound to return 1. and your loop iteration will never repeat.

So that's all. Make sure you think about your EXIT conditions while dealing with loops.